# Finding multiple values ​in a loop

Tags: python, while-loop

Need help finding. The script generates coordinates in a loop. It is necessary for me that search searched for several values ​​at once.
The given range has these coordinates for searching. **wanted** function does not work, this function should look for these values ​​in curve_hex, there are no errors, but there is no search either. Help me understand why this function does not work (**if str(curve_hex).find(wanted)!=-1:**)

```
import os, binascii, bitcoin
while True:
 hex_key = '00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' + binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(2))
 decoded_key = bitcoin.decode_privkey(hex_key,'hex')
 print (hex_key)
 curve_hex=bitcoin.privkey_to_pubkey(decoded_key)
 wanted = ('90040672269639781867601170828097460642155183514693739441068299505511569496110', '54485907183099442435241830545487744604431707282385107218140713089194934994051')
if str(curve_hex).find(wanted)!=-1:
  dosya2 = open("2.txt", "a")
  dosya2.write(hex_key)
  dosya2.close()
```

Recently with Python, I have spent weeks searching for problems.
Just, I want to find patterns in coordinates by trying to find the same X but different Y

Comment: Can you specify what doesn't work?

Comment: Search not working

Comment: Please [edit] your question to say more about what isn't working. Do you see an error message? If so, what is it? It is not producing the expected output? If not, what output do you see and what output do you expect?